# How to change the value of a mutable livedata and display it as a Toast

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I initialised my `mutable live data` **(in my `viewmodel`)** like this:

```
  val networkResponse = MutableLiveData<String>()
```

Then I wanted to change it:

```
 networkResponse.value = "happy birthday"
```

But, when I Logged it:

```
Log.d(TAG,networkResponse.toString())
```

I got *{in the terminal}*

```
com.example.myapplication D/TAG: androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData@12c1fa8
```

I am trying to log out the value but it simply doesn't happen, same occurs when I display it as a toast in my `Main Activity`

Comment: Can you share the code at the activity? how do you implement it

Comment: try `Log.d(TAG, networkResponse.value.toString())`

Comment: why aren't you logging networkResponse.value.toString?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val networkResponse = MutableLiveData<String>()
```

this declares a MutableLiveData **object**.

you change this **object** by calling:

```
networkResponse.value
```

so logging

```
Log.d(TAG,networkResponse.toString())
```

will just log the entire object, what you're looking for is:

```
networkResponse.value
```

so something like:

```
Log.d(TAG, networkResponse.value.toString())
```

Comment: You do need `toString()` because `value` is nullable but the parameter for `d` is nonnullable.